# ElastAlert Needs to send an alert if EFK stops receiving logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, elastalert, efk

I want my elastalert to send an email alert if the elasticsearch(efk stack) stops receives logs after a certain time.,

I tried many ways , but could not able to configure it.. nothing is working for me, can someone please help me to configure it.

Here is one of my ways:

I am using below configuration in rules:

```
es_host: myhost
es_port: myport
index: myindex*
name: zerologs
type: spike
spike_height: 0
timeframe:
  minutes: 15
realert:
  minutes: 10
filter:
- term:
    issue-type: "zerologs"
alert:
- email:
    email: 'receiver@gmail.com'
    smtp_host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_port: 465
    smtp_ssl: true
    from_addr: 'sender@gmail.com'
    smtp_auth_file: '/opt/elastalert/smtp_auth_file.yml'
```

But It is getting error saying like:

```
15:00:35.597Z ERROR elastalert-server:
    TestService:  INFO:elastalert:Note: In debug mode, alerts will be logged to console but NOT actually sent.
                To send them but remain verbose, use --verbose instead.
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/elastalert/elastalert/loaders.py", line 297, in load_options
    
        self.rule_schema.validate(rule)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsonschema-4.9.0-py3.10.egg/jsonschema/validators.py", line 269, in validate
    
        raise error
    
    jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: {'es_host': 'myhost', 'es_port': myport, 'index': 'myindex', 'name': 'zerologs', 'type': 'spike', 'spike_height': 0, 'timeframe': {'minutes': 5}, 'realert': {'minutes': 10}, 'filter': [{'term': {'issue-type': 'zerologs'}}], 'alert': [{'email': {'email': 'receiver@gmail.com', 'smtp_host': 'smtp.gmail.com', 'smtp_port': 465, 'smtp_ssl': True, 'from_addr': 'sender@gmail.xom', 'smtp_auth_file': '/opt/elastalert/smtp_auth_file.yml'}}], 'rule_file': '/opt/elastalert/server_data/tests/~zBxU8hntki8ryDEyh2gjEnTxUk6xFqs5.temp'} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

Comment: you can compare the document count `now` - `now-15m` and if the documents counts are same trigger the notification.